# how to remove a button of "REMOVE" from Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

my question is not about removing any event listeners.
i just want to remove/disable/hide that UI button that appears near any link to event listener function, which you can see in dev tools at Event Listeners tab, while hovering with a mouse. See a printscreen.

i am regularly used to click on the button instead of clicking on a link, and it completely erases the link i am willing to click.., it's embarrassing. Is there any way to disable this wonderful feature?

[image: dev tools]

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about just making the window wider so they’re not as close?

[image]

Comment: no, it is not a comfortable way to deal with that, unfortunately

Comment: How did you do this?